# How to get last day of previous month in DataStage?

Tags: datastage

I explored all the functions available in the transformer, but I couldn't find the exact function to get the last day of the previous month in standard format, i.e. dd/mm/yyyy. Please help me in this regard.

The field that needs to appear is in the COL_C field.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l6lO.png)

inside it I can't put anything that returns me this result

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateOffsetByComponents](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=functions-date-time) to substract the current day.
Cut out the day part from your date and substract it with above function.

i.e. 16/12/2022 - 16 = 30/11/2022